# Oracle TO_CHAR output includes BC

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

When I run

```
select *
```

I don't get my date because they are negativ and i see them with :

```
Select to_char(start_date,'DD/MM/YYYY AD'),s.*
from LIST s
where start_date<to_date('00010101 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss')
order by s.start_date desc
```

But they are written  like `22/03/2016 BC`

Where did the `BC` come from? 
Does someone have a clue on how my date becomes negativ sometimes ?
Because sometimes they are "normal" dates and sometimes they got the BC ...

Comment: What does "written correctly" mean?  The simplest explanation would seem to be that whatever application inserted these values inserted 2016 BC dates.  A `select *` will convert the date to a string using your session's `nls_date_format` which, presumably, doesn't include the AD/ BC suffix.  It's the same way that a date can look OK if you only display 2 digit years despite the year being 0016 rather than 2016.

Comment: Or four-digit years if you leave off the sign. You are filtering on dates < 0001-01-01, so they must all logically be BC. You can also use `to_char(start_date,'SYYYY-MM-DD')` which will show those as -2016. So as Justin says, your issues seems to be with whatever is inserting data with negative (BC) years.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, see my edit.
Ok the bug is coming from whatever is inserting the date in a bad format.

I was wandering if there was something with the to_char etc ...

Comment: Whenever you have doubts about what's in the db vs. what is displayed (for example does to_char() do something to my dates), you can use DUMP to see what is actually stored in the db. For example, select `dump(start_date) from s where start_date < to_date(.....)` How dates are stored is not trivial, you would need to look at the documentation to understand the output, but this will show you directly what is in the db without the intermediation of to_char() or implicit conversion to char.

Answer (score 1):

If your date format model, either explicitly or via your NLS_DATE_FORMAT session parameter, doesn't include the sign of the year or an AD/BC indicator then you can't distinguish between, say, 2016 and -2016 once they are strings.

```
with t (dt) as (
  select date '2016-03-22' from dual
  union all select date '-2016-03-22' from dual
  union all select date '0001-01-01' from dual
  union all select date '-0001-01-01' from dual
)
select to_char(dt, 'SYYYY-MM-DD') as dt1,
  to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as dt2,
  to_char(dt, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as dt3,
  to_char(dt, 'DD/MM/SYYYY') as dt4, 
  to_char(dt, 'DD/MM/YYYY AD') as dt5
from t;

DT1         DT2        DT3        DT4         DT5         
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -------------
 2016-03-22 2016-03-22 22/03/2016 22/03/ 2016 22/03/2016 AD
-2016-03-22 2016-03-22 22/03/2016 22/03/-2016 22/03/2016 BC
 0001-01-01 0001-01-01 01/01/0001 01/01/ 0001 01/01/0001 AD
-0001-01-01 0001-01-01 01/01/0001 01/01/-0001 01/01/0001 BC
```

Notice that the `dt2` and `dt3` columns appear the same for both pairs of positive and negative values, even though the actual dates were different.

Your date values aren't changing, how you are displaying them is. They don't 'become negative' - they *are* negative, for whatever reason, and sometimes the string your convert them to show that. If you change your NLS_DATE_FORMAT to `'SYYYY-MM-DD'` then `select *` will also show them as negative, via implicit conversion using that NLS parameter.

If you are only expecting AD values in your data then you need to investigate how and why BC (negative) values were inserted. That's a completely separate issue to how you are seeing them displayed.

Comment: I will continue to investigate.
Thanks all for your answers :)